# Xamarin Forms video thumbnail: Error occurring when trying to create video thumbnail form local storage on IOS 13.1.3 device

Tags: ios, video, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, thumbnails

Can someone help me with this problem?

Im trying to create a thumbnail from a video saved/created using the [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin). My path that is returned is

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{ApplicationID}/Documents/Videos/{name
>   of video}.MOV

But everytime I try this URL it returns an error saying 'filepath doesn't exists..'

Ive tried appending 'filepath:///', 'file:///', and 'file:///private'. None of these works. Whats wrong with my URL? I know the video exists and I have full access (permission) to my iPhones file system.

The code i'm using:

```
public ImageSource GenerateThumbImage(string url, long usecond)
{      
    AVAssetImageGenerator imageGenerator = new AVAssetImageGenerator(AVAsset.FromUrl((new Foundation.NSUrl(url))));
    imageGenerator.AppliesPreferredTrackTransform = true;
    CMTime actualTime;
    NSError error;
    CGImage cgImage = imageGenerator.CopyCGImageAtTime(new CMTime(usecond, 1000000), out actualTime, out error);
    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new UIImage(cgImage).AsPNG().AsStream());
}
```

Note: I'm using X.Forms 4.1 with MediaPlugin 4.4.8.3 (beta version). iPhone is running on IOS 13.1.3

Comment: try `AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename())`

Comment: @E75 Hi , have you solved it ? I have shared my answer , you can have a look at it when you have time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xamarin Forms ,you can use **[Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/)** to get photo or file from native iOS .

Create a **IThumbnailService** Interface :

```
public interface IThumbnailService 
{
    Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync(string filePath);
}
```

In ios solution , create **ThumbnailService** classs to get thumbnail from a ios local file path :

```
public class ThumbnailService : IThumbnailService
{
    TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskCompletionSource;
    public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync(string filePath)
    {

        CoreMedia.CMTime actualTime;
        NSError outError;
        using (var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath)))
        using (var imageGen = new AVAssetImageGenerator(asset))
        using (var imageRef = imageGen.CopyCGImageAtTime(new CoreMedia.CMTime(1, 1), out actualTime, out outError))
        {
            if (imageRef == null)
                return null;
            var image = UIImage.FromImage(imageRef);

            //Stream imagestream = image.AsJPEG(1).AsStream();
            Stream imagestream = image.AsPNG().AsStream();
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(imagestream);
        }

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Finally , show it in **ContentPage** :

```
Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IThumbnailService>().GetImageStreamAsync("VideoPath");
if (stream != null)
{
    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
}
```